# Weird behaviour of my scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in this field and want to write a app, now I meet some problems. Here is a simple version of my code, what I want is the API only show `signUp` first. After I press `signUp` and press `submit` the button shown should be only `signout`

Now, my scope variable doesn't work, two button show here. Could you modify it and tell me the reason? Please use the rootscope and scope and sc.logIn() if possible so that I can know how to write in this way. Thanks!

https://plnkr.co/edit/ewhLZsKKTWTzlECsj4xO?p=preview

```
angular.module('myApp',['myApp.dashboard','myApp.signUp']);

angular.module('myApp.dashboard').controller('mainControl',mainControl);
mainControl.$inject = ['$rootScope','$scope'];
function mainControl($rootScope,$scope){
  $rootScope.logged=false;
    $scope.logged=$rootScope.logged;
}


angular.module('myApp.signUp').controller('signUpControl',signUpControl);
signUpControl.$inject = ['$rootScope','$scope'];
function signUpControl($rootScope){
    alert("haha");
    this.logIn=function(){
        $rootScope.logged=true;
    };
}
```

Comment: why dont u use ``angular.module('myApp')`` instead of ``angular.module('myApp.dashboard')`` ?

Comment: This would be a large app, so that I want to separate them, also, for learning

Comment: There are numerous things wrong with this code, enough that it can't be easily fixed without being rewritten.  First of all, using `$rootScope` is an anti-pattern.  Secondly, you are actually hiding `$rootScope.logged` by making a new property on `$scope` named the same.  Thirdly, you are mixing `$scope` and `this`, when you should be using one or the other.  Lastly, you are violating the angular binding principle of "always use a dot in bindings" by having a `logged` primitive property.

Comment: bottom line, don't use `$rootScope`, use a service.

Comment: @Claies Could you see this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415322/how-to-set-value-of-one-service-from-one-controller-and-update-value-of-another/40415837#40415837 If I write like this, is $watch necessary here? or could provide one better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of issues with your code.

Whenever you declare a module without a second argument, it just tries to fetch the module that is already declared / defined. In order to create a new module, you need to pass in the dependencies or an empty array, if there are no dependencies.

Also, you need to watch on the changes being done to the scope to ensure your changes are notified to the controllers to make them visible on the view.

Here is the working solution:

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.dashboard', 'myApp.signUp']);

angular.module('myApp.dashboard', []).controller('mainControl', mainControl);

function mainControl($rootScope, $scope) {
  $rootScope.logged = false;
  $rootScope.$watch(() => $rootScope.logged, function() {
    $scope.logged = $rootScope.logged;
  });
}

mainControl.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope'];

angular.module('myApp.signUp', []).controller('signUpControl', signUpControl);
signUpControl.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope'];

function signUpControl($rootScope) {
  this.logIn = function() {
    var a = 1;
    $rootScope.logged = true;
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainControl as mc">
    <div>{{mc.logged}}
      <div ng-hide="logged">

        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".signUp">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="logged">
        <button>Sign Out</button>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="signUp modal fade" id="signUp" ng-controller='signUpControl as sc'>
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">sigh up</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="signUpForm" name="signUpForm" ng-submit="sc.logIn()">
              <label for="email">
                <span>email:</span>
                <input type="email" name="email">
              </label>
              <button class="submit" id="signUpSubmit" type="submit" value="signUp">submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason the code snippet doesnt let me submit the form.

You can find a working solution here : [Codepen](http://codepen.io/jsreekanth/pen/ZBELPw?editors=1010)

Comment: The `$watch()` here works, but it would be unnecessary if the properties were objects instead of primitives, if the properties were not named the same, and/or if a service was used instead.  While this may actually work, it's a messy solution that should be avoided, in my opinion.

Comment: I agree with you on this. However,  to answer on the problem asked I came up with the modifications.

Comment: i dont understand, can you be specific please?

Comment: Do you know what Claies means by: 1 $rootScope is an anti-pattern 2 hiding $rootScope.logged by making a new property on $scope named the same (because your code make same mistake) 3 mixing $scope and this 4 always use a dot in bindings Thanks! Those stuff are in my question comments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415322/how-to-set-value-of-one-service-from-one-controller-and-update-value-of-another/40415396#40415396 could you answer this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not weird at all.
Open your console, it shows errors.
Your main problem is angular bootstrap error.

```
angular.module('myApp.dashboard', [])
-------------------------------   ^^  ------- must be an array even empty
```

Comment: you can leave it like this ``angular.module('myApp.dashboard')``

Comment: this answer fixes the script issues and allows angular to run correctly.  It doesn't fix the underlying issue in the question, though;  `$scope.logged` and `$rootScope.logged` are still detached from each other, for reasons outlined in my comment on the original post.