# How to set value of one service from one controller, and update value of another controller with this service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in this field and want to write a app, now I meet some problems. Here is a simple version of my code, what I want is the API only show `signUp` first. After I press `signUp` and press `submit` the button shown should be only `signout`

I think my way is not all right, because after I change the value in service, another controller can't update its value. Could you tell me that?
please use `this.logged` if possible, thanks!

The process is not necessary to be same to my title. OK if it can implement my function.

https://plnkr.co/edit/1ptaVzmD7EwPZ6dU23gR?p=preview

```
(function(){
    angular.module('myApp',['myApp.dashboard','myApp.value','myApp.signUp']);
})();

(function(){
    angular.module('myApp.dashboard',[]);
})();

(function(){
    angular.module('myApp.value',[]);
})();

(function(){
    angular.module('myApp.signUp',[]);
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.dashboard').controller('mainControl',mainControl);

    mainControl.$inject = ['whichToShow'];
    function mainControl(whichToShow){
        this.logged=whichToShow.getVar();
        alert(this.logged);
    }
})();



(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.value').factory('whichToShow',function(){
        alert("running2");
        var logged=false;
        return {
            getVar: function(){
                return logged;
            },
            setVar: function(value){
                logged=value;
            }

        };
    });
})();

(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.signUp').controller('signUpControl',signUpControl);
    signUpControl.$inject = ['whichToShow'];
    function signUpControl(whichToShow){
        alert("haha");
        this.logIn=function(){
            whichToShow.setVar(true);
            alert("running set!");
        };
    };
})();
```

partial html:

```
<body ng-controller="mainControl as mc">
    <div>
        <div ng-hide="mc.logged">
                <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".signUp">Sign Up</button>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="mc.logged">
                <button>Sign Out</button>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="signUp modal fade" id="signUp" ng-controller='signUpControl as sc'>
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">sigh up</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form id="signUpForm" name="signUpForm" ng-submit="sc.logIn()">
                            <label for="email">
                                <span>email:</span>
                                <input type="email" name="email">
                            </label>
                            <button class="submit" id="signUpSubmit" type="submit" value="signUp">submit</button>
                        </form>                 
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need watch for the changes on the logged value from the service.

That is all you need to do.

```js
(function() {
  angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.dashboard', 'myApp.value', 'myApp.signUp']);
})();

(function() {
  angular.module('myApp.dashboard', []);
})();

(function() {
  angular.module('myApp.value', []);
})();

(function() {
  angular.module('myApp.signUp', []);
})();

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp.dashboard').controller('mainControl', mainControl);

  mainControl.$inject = ['$scope', 'whichToShow'];

  function mainControl($scope, whichToShow) {
    $scope.$watch(() => whichToShow.getVar(), (newValue, oldValue) => this.logged = newValue)
  }
})();

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp.value').factory('whichToShow', function() {

    var logged = false;
    var service = {};

    return {
      getVar: function() {
        return logged;
      },
      setVar: function(value) {
        logged = value;
      }

    }
  });
})();

(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp.signUp').controller('signUpControl', signUpControl);
  signUpControl.$inject = ['whichToShow'];

  function signUpControl(whichToShow) {
    this.logIn = function() {
      whichToShow.setVar(true);
    };
  };
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="mainControl as mc">
    <div>
      <div ng-hide="mc.logged">

        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".signUp">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
      <div ng-show="mc.logged">
        <button>Sign Out</button>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="signUp modal fade" id="signUp" ng-controller='signUpControl as sc'>
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">sigh up</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">&times;</button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="signUpForm" name="signUpForm" ng-submit="sc.logIn()">
              <label for="email">
                <span>email:</span>
                <input type="email" name="email">
              </label>
              <button class="submit" id="signUpSubmit" type="submit" value="signUp">submit</button>
            </form>


          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Working solution on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/jsreekanth/pen/LbYWwO?editors=1011)

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are setting values in factory object after user clicks on submit but that doesn't reflect in UI as you have not updated the scope object `this.logged`.So to tell main controller fromsign up controller that change the `this.logged $scope` value we can use `$emit` or `$broadcast`

Apart from `$watch` approach you can even use `$broadcast` to achieve this.

Working [**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/qeXJV8Yv8Ab5FkFBqTjT?p=preview)

Just add this below code in your JS file controllers

**signUpControl**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.signUp').controller('signUpControl',signUpControl);
    signUpControl.$inject = ['whichToShow','$rootScope'];
    function signUpControl(whichToShow,$rootScope){
        alert("haha");
        this.logIn=function(){
            whichToShow.setVar(true);
            $rootScope.$broadcast('login');//broadcasting that user has logged in
            //alert("running set!");
        };
    };
})
```

**mainControl**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';
    angular.module('myApp.dashboard').controller('mainControl',mainControl);

    mainControl.$inject = ['whichToShow','$rootScope'];

    function mainControl(whichToShow,$rootScope){
        var mc = this;
        mc.main ={};
        mc.main.logged=whichToShow.getVar();
        alert(mc.main.logged);

       // below code will listen to the broadcast and do the necessary process..
        $rootScope.$on('login',function(event,args){
                mc.main.logged=whichToShow.getVar();
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You are still trying to set the value of primitives here, rather than object properties.  In JavaScript, primitives are passed *byValue*, not *byReference*, so `whichToShow.getVar();` is returning `true` or `false` rather than returning a reference to `logged`.  Therefore, you won't see changes to `logged` unless you call `.getVar()` again, to get the new value.  This is why most answers you have seen so far have had some form of `$watch`, `$broadcast`, or similar, to alert your `mc` that it should ask again for the `logged` variable's current value.

If you want to avoid using a `$watch`, you should use an object instead of a primitive.  by using an object, you can pass the object *byReference*, which will allow angular to see the changes to the properties wherever there is a reference set.

In your factory, return an object:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp.value').factory('whichToShow', function() {
    alert("running2");
    var status = {
      logged: false
    };
    var logged = false;
    return {
      getVar: function() {
        return status;
      },
      setVar: function(value) {
        status.logged = value;
      }

    };
  });
})();
```

In mainControl, use a reference to this object:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('myApp.value').factory('whichToShow', function() {
    alert("running2");
    var status = {
      logged: false
    };
    return {
      getVar: function() {
        return status;
      },
      setVar: function(value) {
        status.logged = value;
      }

    };
  });
})();
```

And finally, use the object property in the HTML:

```
<div ng-hide="mc.status.logged">
...
<div ng-show="mc.status.logged">
...
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Pindt2LYxDxyk8C5Axp1?p=preview

I might even go one step further and just return the object directly by the service, and skip the `getVar` and `setVar` functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can put some variable globally or in your rootcontroller,lets says isLoggedIn

now with one service you can set this variable on signingIn

and use it like this
{

}`<span data-ng-if="!isLoggedIn">Sign In</span>
<span data-ng-if="isLoggedIn">Sign Out</span>`